# scripts file is not connecting/loading

Tags: javascript

Losing my mind here. I feel like I have the paths correct but for some reason my script file isn't loading/working. When I move the code to the app.js it prints out what I want to the console and works just fine but when I have it in the scripts file, it does nothing. I cant seem to find the problem.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const rootRoute = require('./routes/index')

app.use('/', rootRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('server is running')
});
```

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>In Your Words</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
</head>
<body>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script page

```
const generateInputs = () => {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    console.log(randomNumber)
}

generateInputs();
```

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know that it is connected I guess. generateInputs simply isn't printing out a random number. It prints out a number when I put the code in my app.js file and am not sure why it isn't working in my scripts file.

Comment: Your file is connected or not depend on your folder structure, you you post your folder structure , how you are having files